# Difference between "COMPRESS FOR ALL OPERATIONS" and "COMPRESS FOR OLTP"?

Tags: database, oracle

I was looking through Oracle's OLTP Table Compression (11g onwards) documentation as well as online resources to find the syntax and came across two different versions:

```
COMPRESS FOR ALL OPERATIONS
```

and

```
COMPRESS FOR OLTP
```

The documentation I looked through didn't mention any alternative syntax, so i was wondering if anyone here might know the difference.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`COMPRESS FOR ALL OPERATIONS` and `COMPRESS FOR OLTP` are just synonyms according to [Vadzim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/603516/vadzim).

On the OTN forums an oracle Ace says it's just a new name for the same thing.

http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1042141&tstart=0

The same is stated here:

http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/TableCompressionEnhancements_11gR1.php

`COMPRESS` or `COMPRESS FOR DIRECT_LOAD OPERATIONS` is part of the regular Oracle EE database, as stated in [the PDF](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/database/oracle11g/pdf/advanced-compression-whitepaper.pdf) [APC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/146325/apc) linked to.

> It should be noted that Basic Table Compression is a base feature of Oracle Database 11g
> Enterprise Edition (EE). OLTP Table Compression is a part of the Oracle Advanced
> Compression option, which requires a license in addition to the Enterprise Edition.

Comment: To make in clearer: `COMPRESS FOR ALL OPERATIONS` and `COMPRESS FOR OLTP` are just synonyms.